# How can we use @Html.EditorFor to display user password?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How can we use @Html.EditorFor to display user password ?
One alternative can be to use @Html.PasswordFor.
Which option is more suitable and any specific reason for introducing this editor helper.

Comment: What's the context of your question, are you using the built in identity 2.0?  If so passwords are encrypted by default, you can't view them once they have been created.  If you are using your own password/login system them just call the data from the table and place it into a viewmodel for the page in your controller.  Then call the @Html.Editorfor helper on your page on the relevant field in your viewmodel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To generate an input with `type="password"` using `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password)`, you can either decorate you property with a `DataTypeAttribute`

```
[DataType(DataType.Password)]
public string Password { get; set; }
```

or (for MVC-5.1 or higher only) you can add the attribute using

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "password" } })
```

The recommended approach is to use `@Html.PasswordFor()` because it does not send the value of the property in the request. All the `HtmlHelper` methods that generate form controls except `PasswordFor()` populate the input from `ModelState` values if they exist, or from the models value. In the case of `EditorFor()`, if you return the view because of an error, the password is passed to the client and the value will be displayed (albeit as a series of dots in the control). That just increases the risk of a hacker intercepting the request and discovering the password. The `PasswordFor()` method does not pass the value to the client and the input will be blank, forcing the user to re-enter the password (which is what should happen).